# Tables Analysis

Tags: database

I have an Input form for enter Students Data , So I tried to design Database to 
store these Data ..
 My Question is : Is the design of StudentMarks Table Correct or not ? , if there are any notes I will be glad to know it .

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to design a database for a school, there are sample designs available. You can check this sample from Microsoft with code and model at: [Creating the School Sample Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399731(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your time and for the link .